# Docker not publishing ports

Tags: docker

I ran

```
docker run -d --name=sonarr 
-e PUID=1000 
-e PGID=100 
-e TZ=Europe/London 
-p 10000:8989 
-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/__docker_configs/:/config 
-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/_downloads:/downloads 
-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-other/_bin:/bin 
-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-other/documentaries:/documentaries 
--restart unless-stopped 
ghcr.io/linuxserver/sonarr:develop
```

from the terminal and it didn’t publish the ports.

I’ve had the develop branch running for almost a year with no issues. I have been using Portainer to manage things for a while. I had to make a path change to map a folder for Sonarr to use for its trash folder.

I made the changes as I’ve done probably hundreds of times before on this and other containers but this time the ports didn’t publish.

I then removed the container and images and tried to create from the terminal, but the ports didn’t publish that way either.

At this point I’m not sure why they aren’t publishing.

I’ve also used the default image to with no luck. The configuration apart from the bin volume is the same as it’s been from the start.

I’ve also tried it without the bin volume in it, still doesn’t mount the ports.

I tried to create a different container with a different image and ports both through Portainer and the terminal and it created correctly and published the ports.

At this point I’m stumped.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the output of`docker ps` after running the posted command?

Comment: Why do you think the ports aren't being published?  Is the application code in your image listening on the second port number (8989), on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address?  Bind-mounting a directory over the system `/bin` directory is likely to cause some operational trouble, though it shouldn't directly interfere with the networking setup.

Comment: I know the ports aren't being published because I can't see them in Portainer and when I visit localhost:10000 the site doesn't load.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you remove -p and instead use -P to allow docker to take care of mapping it to a port on host?

Comment: Well, damn. Looks like I must not have tried it with the bin mapping removed. I changed the bin mapping from /bin to /sonarr_bin and republished the container and the container came up and the ports have been published.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was caused by this line

`-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-other/_bin:/bin`

I changed it to

`-v /srv/dev-disk-by-label-other/_bin:/sonarr_bin`

and after creating the container the ports got published.